# shutil.chown() for Python2

Tags: python

Is there a library which does provide [shutil.chown](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/shutil.html#shutil.chown) in Python2?

I know that this work around works:

```
import pwd
import grp
import os

uid = pwd.getpwnam("nobody").pw_uid
gid = grp.getgrnam("nogroup").gr_gid
path = '/tmp/f.txt'
os.chown(path, uid, gid)
```

Above code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5995007/633961

I don't want to use the above work-around, I prefer to reuse.

Comment: why not write your own wrapper to emulate it?  The python guys might accept a patch for a new `from future` thing

Comment: @chicks Python2 is a dead end. But I still have some Python2 systems running. I don't want to invest much time into Python2. Python3 already has it.

Comment: It sounds like you should use python3 then.

Comment: @chicks I choose Python3 in all projects where I am able to choose the Python version. In some projects I am just a small sheep and there is no one willing to pay the time which is needed to do the update to Python3.

Comment: What do you mean you prefer to reuse?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.3/Lib/shutil.py#L994

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples With "I prefer to reuse" I mean this: I prefer to install a library from pypi to copy-and-pasting code. Even if the library just installs one methods which is made of five lines of code. Does this answer your question?